# "Apply with LinkedIN" button does not render properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, linkedin-api

I have successfully added <kbd>Apply with LinkedIN</kbd> button on website, the problem i have i styling that button. Very strange  display of the button, i am using bootstrap 3.1.
Any other had a similar problem, is there any fix?

Have tried many solution n overriding my css, but i got no luck, becuase all is done from JS

[image]

Here is the code I have from API

```
<script type="IN/Apply" 
    data-email="example@example.com" 
    data-companyid="55885" 
    data-jobtitle='Developer' 
    data-joblocation='Serbia'
    data-themeColor="#FF9900" 
    data-showText="false">
</script>
```

Comment: A client of mine received a notice email that the "Apply with LinkedIn" plugin was to be removed very soon, on July 31.  I was about to post a comment here regarding this, then I found that I could find little to no evidence on the internet that this is true. Only [this forum thread](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/apply-linkedin-migration-plugin-profile-api) regarding the necessary migration away from the plugin.  Did anyone else receive the same notification of the plugin's removal?  Is "Apply with LinkedIn" going away, or not?

Comment: [This link](https://developer.linkedin.com/apply-with-linkedin) is slightly more conclusive. 4th paragraph: "the Apply with LinkedIn plugin is being retired".  I wonder why there is so little mention of this?  The [plugin page](https://developer.linkedin.com/apply) suggests business as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because the LinkedIN script doesn't work well together with `box-sizing : border-box` (used by the latest versions of Twitter Bootstrap).

If so, it is the same problem of [this topic](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/apply-linkedin-does-not-work-box-sizingborder-box), and the solution could be to add this snippet to your CSS:

```css
span[id*='li_ui_li_gen_'] {
    -webkit-box-sizing : content-box;
       -moz-box-sizing : content-box;
         -o-box-sizing : content-box;
            box-sizing : content-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After few tries prepared a simple override CSS for this kind of problem.
Please add this to your css

```
span.IN-widget span span a span {
    width:180px !important;    
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted LinkedIn deprecated this feature on July 21, 2014. They suggest the functionality should be rebuilt with the Profile API. http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/7234/~/apply-with-linkedin%3A-no-longer-supported